# C# - Inconsistent Accessibility: return type list is less accessible than method

Tags: c#

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public class StudentBusinessLayer
    {
        public List<Student> getStudents(string storedProcedure)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, conn);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Student s = new Student();
                    s.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
                    s.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    s.TotalMarks = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalMarks"]);

                    students.Add(s);
                }
                return students;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you ever googled it? it's the first result of google,

Answer (score 7):

It seems that your `Student` class is not `public`, make it `public` to fix your error.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your reply! Such a silly mistake, I did not look into it.

Comment: You're welcome, kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Your return is in the wrong block:

```
namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public class StudentBusinessLayer
    {
        public List<Student> getStudents(string storedProcedure)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, conn);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                   Student s = new Student();
                   s.id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["id"]);
                   s.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                   s.TotalMarks = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["TotalMarks"]);

                    students.Add(s);
                }
            }

            return students;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I was doing some other trial and error method, so put it their. Thanks for pointing out though!

Comment: No problem.  Was the other guy right about your class `Student` not being `public`?  That would obviously also be a problem.